# Exclude argument ignored when Dump'ing an OnDemand / DumpContainer

Tags: c#, linqpad

***Edit - This has been fixed as of v6.11.11!***

I was trying to dump a result set in two different ways depending a flag property using `Util.OnDemand` and found that it was not working as expected. I was able to reproduce it with this small example:

```
    void Main()
    {
        var i = new Test() { Prop1 = "One" };
        i.Dump(exclude:"Prop1");
        Util.OnDemand("On Demand Exclude Prop1", ()=>i).Dump(exclude:"Prop1");
    }
    
    public class Test
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Output:

```
    Test
    UserQuery+Test

    On Demand Exclude Prop1
```

After clicking the `Util.OnDemand` link:

```
    Test
    UserQuery+Test

    Test
    UserQuery+Test
    Prop1 One
```

Expected Result:

```
    Test
    UserQuery+Test

    Test
    UserQuery+Test
```

I'm fairly sure this is not related to `Util.OnDemand` directly but more likely a problem with `DumpContainer` as this also produces the same non-excluded result:

```cs
    new DumpContainer(i).Dump(exclude:"Prop1");
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Any potential work arounds?

I haven't checked every parameter but I have confirmed `collapseTo` is also misbehaving when invoked in this fashion, potentially others are as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal behavior: options such as `include` and `exclude` should operate on the content of the dump container, not the container itself. I'll get a fix into the next LINQPad build. In the meantime, the suggested workarounds look good.

Comment: Hey you fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that's possible. My understanding is `Dump(exclude:"")` excludes property from the object that the method was called on. In your case you run it on `LINQPad.DumpContainer` object that doesn't have `Prop1` property. I was not able to exclude `Prop1` from `DumpContainer.Content`.

Clean and recommended solution is to overwrite `ToDump` method:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

object ToDump()
{
   IDictionary<string,object> custom = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

   var props = GetType().GetProperties (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
       .Where (p => p.Name != "Prop1");

   foreach (var prop in props)
      custom[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue (this);
      
   return custom;
}
}
```

Other way, if you don't want to write additional methods, would be to convert it to `ExpandoObject` first, which will result in ugly one liner:

```cs
Util.OnDemand("On Demand Exclude Prop1", () => (Util.ToExpando(i, exclude:"Prop1"))).Dump()
```

Comment: Thanks! Since my actual use-cause is an anonymous type the `ToExpando` option looks pretty good in the short term.